# Simple is condition python int

Tags: python, int

Is a simple whay to right this code ?

```
if a == b - 25 or a == b - 24 or a == b - 23...
or a - 25 == b or a - 24 == b or a - 23 == b...
```

Comment: `if abs(a-b) <= 25:`

Comment: How would you describe the condition you want in words?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```py
nums = [..., 23, 24, 25]
if any(a == b - x for x in nums):
    # code
```

Answer (score 1):

for or :

```
if any([(a==b-i) for i in range(25,0,-1)]):
    #do something
```

and for and:

```
if all([(a==b-i) for i in range(25,0,-1)]):
    #do something
```